# Failing to insert values from pubsub to Big query in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to Python Apache beam and trying to perform a task to pull values from pubsub and pass it to big query using Google Cloud dataflow. Please find the steps below that I followed for this scenario.

1) data is pushed as json into pubsub topic.
{-----record1 ----}{---record2---} and so on

2) Big query table follows exactly the same key as per the json pushed to pubsub and all the columns are of string type.

3) Below is the code for the scenario

```
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
p_bq = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
logging.info('Start')

BQ_data1 = (p_bq 
            | 'readPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='subscriptionname') 
            | 'writeBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table='table name', 
                                                   dataset='dataset',
                                                   project='projectname'))
result_bq = p_bq.run()
```

Expected result: Passing the value from pubsub to big query

Actual result:
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting raw strings out of pubsub, not python objects.
You likely need to parse the json strings into python objects (or dictionaries) before you can write them to BQ. See this example: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/windowed_wordcount.py#L71